# Propagate state between different pages

Tags: flutter, callback, flutter-state, flutter-http

I've three different `MaterialPage`. So I use `Navigator.push` to go from 1 -> 2 -> 3.
Now, page 1 make an HTTP request to `GET` a model that is then used in page 1, 2 and 3.
At the end of the process an action on page 3 triggers some modification of the model on the server. How can I update the tree pages on the stack to reflect these changes? In order to do that I need to make a `GET` request again.
Should I pass a callback from page 1 to 3 and then go back all the way up to page 1 (and then down again...), or duplicate the HTTP request in page 3? Or something else?
I've attached a schema, in order to clarify (I hope) my explanation. Thanks in advance.

[image: Flutter schema]

Comment: what state management system you are using?

Comment: You could just use a global `state` for that, so all your components update automatically as soon as the `Model` state/variable changes. Upon that, you can rebuild your widget or whatsoever.

Comment: Use a state management like Riverpod; GetIt etc... Or use the await Navigator.push like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-JyTMKWzsI

Comment: I'm not using a state management tool at the moment, I've had a look at provider, but what confuse me is that I've different Pages not a single tree with children. Where should i put the GET Logic? Where should i define the model? At root level?

Comment: I'd suggest using flutter_bloc and look at cubits. Working in Flutter without a proper state management is very difficult. You can perform the networking in the cubit (in case you don't have a proper structure with repository pattern for example) and emit states to widgets listening to this cubit.

Comment: does your UPDATE request return the updated model from server or you must perform a GET again to get the updated model ?

Comment: @CalvinGonsalves I must perform a GET again.